# Asynchronous tcp client in C# connecting to API... Sporadic errors

Tags: c#, api, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I am writing a TCP Client in C# that is meant to connect to a 3rd-party API server. The vendor is insisting the problem is our code. They have provided a sample TCP client .exe to test against their API. I am generally successful connecting to their API with their app and using Packet Sender. I cannot figure out the problem in my code, though, so I'm hoping I can get some help seeing where I'm going wrong.

I have to make an initial call to ensure a setting is correct, then I can make my API call. It seems as though the API call only returns results when I make my call asynchronously. I'll get successful results 2 or 3 times in a row, and then I'll get an error message that is indecipherable without access to the vendor's source code. I got this code from an MSDN sample or someplace else reputable, but I still seem to get an error from the API (it hangs up and stops responding until I restart it) every 5th call or so (it's inconsistent when I get the error). Can someone help me debug my code? I'm genericizing it so that I'm not putting anything specific to the vendor's API here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tcp
{
    class AsyncClient
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetInitialSetting();
            ConnectAsTcpClient();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SetInitialSetting()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            string stringData;
            IPAddress ip;
            int port;
            int recv;
            IPAddress.TryParse(@"127.0.0.1", out ip);
            port = 10000;
            SetInitialSettingString();
            Console.WriteLine("[Client] Writing request {0}", ClientRequestString);
            using (var client = new TcpClient(ip.ToString(), port))
            {
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                ns.Write(ClientRequestBytes, 0, ClientRequestBytes.Length);
                stringData = "";
                do
                {
                    recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stringData = stringData + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                }
                while (ns.DataAvailable);
                Console.WriteLine("[Client] Server response was {0}", stringData);
                ns.Close();
            }
        }

        private static async void ConnectAsTcpClient()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[10025];
            IPAddress ip;
            int port;
            IPAddress.TryParse(@"127.0.0.1", out ip);
            port = 10000;
            using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Client] Connecting to server");
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
                Console.WriteLine("[Client] Connected to server");
                using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    SetAPICallString();
                    Console.WriteLine("[Client] Writing request {0}", ClientRequestString);
                    await networkStream.WriteAsync(ClientRequestBytes, 0, ClientRequestBytes.Length);
                    var buffer = new byte[4096];
                    var byteCount = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("[Client] Server response was {0}", response);
                }
            }
        }

        private static string ClientRequestString;
        private static byte[] ClientRequestBytes;
        private static void SetInitialSettingString()
        {
            ClientRequestString = "StringThatSetsTheAPISettingGoesHere";
            ClientRequestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClientRequestString);
        }

        private static void SetAPICallString()
        {
            ClientRequestString = "StringForTheCallToTheAPIThatINeedGoesHere";
            ClientRequestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClientRequestString);
        }
    }
}
```